# textcolor not applied to listview item

Tags: android, styles

So, I have a custom list adapter.  In my list adapter, I have:

```
txtLedgerDate.setTypeface(typewriterFont, R.style.grayText);
txtLedgerPayee.setTypeface(typewriterFont, R.style.boldText_gray);
txtLedgerDeposit.setTypeface(typewriterFont, R.style.grayText);
txtLedgerWithdrawal.setTypeface(typewriterFont, R.style.grayText);
```

The style is defined as such:

```
<style name="grayText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray</item>
</style>

<style name="boldText.gray">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>  
</style>
```

However, the text is appearing neither gray nor bold.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: at first glance I'm guessing that `R.style.boldText_gray` doesn't align with `boldText.gray`.  Where did you find reference to Android doing a translation from . to _ in this manner, on its own for you?

Comment: Android reads "." separated as "_" in source code.

Comment: @qkzoo1978 I dont think thats true, I think `boldText.gray` is a child of `boldtext`. At least thats what I read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance

Comment: Well, in any case, I changed the style name to boldTextGray, and the text is still just black.  The other text "grayText" is also just black.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, your `_` trick seems to be legit. I'm messing around with it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong method to apply the style.

```
TextView#setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style)
```

expects the `style` parameter to be one of `Typeface.NORMAL`, `Typeface.BOLD`,
`Typeface.ITALIC`, `Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC`. You need to use the proper method

```
TextView#setTextAppearance(Context context, int resid)
```

So, in your case it is `setTextAppearance(context, R.style.boldText_gray)`.